# for a popup at a run time and bind a data in this popup in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to display a modal popup when gridview row is clicked at a run time, i  managed to display popup alert message by clicking the gridview row but dont know to bind values to textbox displayed in modal popup.. So i need help to

Bind gridview row(when clicked) values to modal popup textboxes
Modal popup textboxes should only be editable when a edit button(placed at bottom of modal popup) is clicked
After editing work is done, it should save the edited data when clicked save button(placed at bottom next to edit button)
As am new to C# please try to help me with your suggestions for my requirements. Because of below code am able to show popup wen clicked gridview row but suggest me how to bind values to textbox:

```
private void childWindow(InspectionResults selectedInspectionResults, ReportMapper reportMapper)
{
    List<string> checklistNameList = new List<string>();
    for (int checklistIndex = 0; checklistIndex < reportMapper.m_ChecklistInfoList.Count; checklistIndex++)
    {
        ReportMapper.ChecklistInfo checklistInfo = reportMapper.m_ChecklistInfoList[checklistIndex];
        checklistNameList.Add(checklistInfo.m_ChecklistName);
    }

    Checklist myForm = QuickSearch.ChecklistFinder.GetChecklistById(checklistId);

    DataTable taskTable = new DataTable();

    // Create the columns.
    taskTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    // taskTable.Columns.Add("CheckBox", typeof(bool)); 

    CheckBox checkBoxButton = new CheckBox();
    checkBoxButton.ID = "selectCheckBoxButton";
    checkBoxButton.Checked = false;

    //  e.Row.Cells[columnNames[columnsCount].clickableIndex].Controls.Add(checkBoxButton);
    taskTable.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

    //Add data to the new table.
    for (int i = 0; i < checklistNameList.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
        tableRow["Id"] = i;
        // tableRow["selectCheckBoxButton"].
        tableRow["Description"] = checklistNameList[i].ToString();
        //  tableRow["IsComplete"] = false;
        taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
    }

    ////Persist the table in the Session object.
    Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

    GridView popup = new GridView();
    popup.ID = "selection";
    string message = " Correlated Checklists";
    string msg = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('"  + message + "','toolbar=no,"
                                                 + "location=yes,status=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,"
                                                 + "resizable=yes, width=850,height=600,left=230,top=23')</SCRIPT>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "scriptBlockName", msg);
    return;

}
```